# Newly Cloned NVMe won't boot on laptop

Tags: fedora, boot, ssd, cloning, nvme

In my fairly old laptop running Fedora 38 I have an normal 2.5" SSD drive. The laptop has a NVMe slot so I added a NVMe drive into the laptop.

1. I Installed the NVMe drive into the laptop and booted the system
2. After rebooting, Fedora can see the new NVMe drive in the Disk Utility.
3. In Terminal I ran

   ```
   echo 'add_drivers+=" nvme "' > /etc/dracut.conf.d/nvme.conf

   sudo dracut -f --no-hostonly --add-drivers nvme --kver 6.3.8-200.fc38.x86_64
   ```

4. I that shutdown the computer.
5. Rebooted using a Clonezilla Live Boot USB
6. Cloned the old SSD to the new NVME
7. Shutdown again
8. Removed the old SSD

When I booted I get this error

Screenshot
[image]

I think I’m still missing something? Do I need recreate/edit grub or make the drive bootable? Can I fix this or do I need to do all that again?

Comment: Have you updated firmware for both UEFI & NVMe drive?

Comment: When you get that message, press Enter to get a root shell in initramfs environment. What does `cat /proc/cmdline` say? Do the devices in `cat /proc/partitions` look as expected? Are the `/dev/nvme0n1p*` devices available? Does `/etc/fstab` contain a reference to `/dev/sd*` that needs to be changed to `/dev/nvme...` form?